# User Registration - Login Code Error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error with this block of code for a registration form I am building to access a new program I am building.

The error is that on line 3 `'Login'` is not highlighted colour when it should be, and it's throwing up an error CS0246. `new Login()` is also not working

Using VSC2015 C#

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Login login = new login();
    login.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Login login = new Login(); //C# is case sensitive. You passed the object name instead of Class/Form name
    login.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if this is basic. I am a beginner.